# how to write path of external file in an included c++ source

Tags: c++, path, code-organization, ifstream

Suppose I'm writing a library or a set of tools `mytool` where a class `MyTool` that other people can use is defined. Suppose I have a directory tree like this:

```
project
| - program1
    | - main1.cpp
...
| - mytool
    | - mytool.h
    | - mytool.cpp
    | - data.txt
```

in `tool1.cpp` I use the external binary huge file `data.dat`:

```
ifsteam f("data.txt");
```

the `main1.cpp` use mytool, but if `mytool.(s)o` is linked with `main1.o` the program can't find `data.dat`, for this case I need to change the previous line to:

```
ifstream f("../mytool/data.txt");
```

but I can't know where other people put `mytool` for example they can have a different directory tree:

```
project
| - program1
    | - main1.cpp
    | - mytool
        | - tool1.h
        | - tool2.cpp
        | - data.dat
```

In addition (am I right?) the path depend on where the program is executed.

The only solution I can imagine is to pass to the class contructor `MyTool` the path of `data.dat` but I want to keep hidden this file for the user.

Comment: Consider using the `boost::filesystem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the absolute path of the file, or else the path of the file relative to your working directory. One approach is to have a configuration script which the user runs before compiling your program. The script then hardcodes into your program the relevant path, so the program has the path hardwired in a manner customized for the user.

Sometimes that's not an option because you don't want to distribute the source code, or because you wish to allow the path to change at runtime. Then you can read a configuration file at runtime which says where the file is. But this is just a layer of abstraction: you still need to know where that configuration file is. You might, for example, ask the system where the user's personal directory is, and then find the file there at that directory. This is a sort of mix between compile-time and runtime computation of the path.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use an environment variable for the location of your tools. For instance, name it MYTOOLDIR. You can set the path on installation of MyTool. A call to `getenv("MYTOOLDIR");` can resolve the path.

On windows, within the mytool dir, run `SETX PATH=%PATH%;./`, or on Linux, just `PATH=$PATH:./`. (Provide a set_env.bat or whatnot to do it.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make the location of the binary file a configuration value that the user defines on a particular installation of the program.  Or, more easily, just always put the binary file in the same place as the final executable and use "data.dat" as the path.